# Problema de envio no Webservice call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope)

Tags: android, web-service

Tenho um serviço que quando acesso pelo navegador ele mostra o xml através do comando "http://localhost:8080/ServicoWeb1/services/CServico?wsdl".

Fiz uma aplicação teste para testar a conexão e quando chega no comando `Tranport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope)` o log de erros está apresentando mensagens de erros relacionadas ao transporte. Erro Abaixo:

```
01-22 19:42:39.515: W/System.err(27880): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 01-22 19:42:39.515: W/System.err(27880):   
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166) 01-22 19:42:39.515: W/System.err(27880):   
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84) 01-22 19:42:39.515: W/System.err(27880):   
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144) 01-22 19:42:39.515: W/System.err(27880):     
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112) 01-22 19:42:39.515: W/System.err(27880):  
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192) 01-22 19:42:39.515: W/System.err(27880):  
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460) 01-22 19:42:39.515: W/System.err(27880):  
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):    
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):   
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):  
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):    
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):  
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):    
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):  
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):   
    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):   
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:152) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):     
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):  
    at com.example.teste2.MainActivity.autenticausuario(MainActivity.java:164) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):     
    at com.example.teste2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:194) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):  
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):  
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19425) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):     
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):     
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):     
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):     
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):   
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):    
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):    
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 01-22 19:42:39.525: W/System.err(27880):   
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-22 19:42:39.535: D/Toast(27880):  checkMirrorLinkEnabled returns : false 01-22 19:42:39.535: D/Toast(27880): showing allowed
```

**SEGUE O CÓDIGO DA APLICAÇÃO:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private static       String      SOAP_ACTION = null;
    private static       String      METHOD_NAME = null;
    private static final String      NAMESPACE   = "http://192.168.0.102:8080/";
    private static final String      URL         = "http://192.168.0.102:8080/ServicoWeb1/services/CServico";
    private ImageView imLogo;
    private EditText edtLogin;
    private EditText edtSenha;
    private TextView textLogin;
    private TextView textSenha;
    private String Login;
    private String Senha;
    private TableLayout tabela;
    private TableRow linha;
    private Button validar;
    private WindowManager wm;
    private int width;
    private int heigth;
    private int Retorno;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(this.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        width = display.getHeight();
        heigth = display.getWidth();

        //setando variáveis de referencia
        imLogo = new ImageView(this);
        imLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.logo_fiat);        
        //imLogo.setOnClickListener(this);

        tabela = new TableLayout(this);
        tabela.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tabela.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
        tabela = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabela1);
        textLogin = new TextView(this);
        textLogin.setText("Login");
        textSenha = new TextView(this);
        textSenha.setText("Senha");
        edtLogin = new EditText(this);
        edtSenha = new EditText(this);
        edtSenha.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
        validar = new Button(this);
        validar.setOnClickListener(this);
        validar.setText("Entrar");      

        linha = new TableRow (this);
        linha.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        linha.addView(textLogin);
        tabela.addView(linha);

        linha = new TableRow (this);
        linha.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        linha.addView(edtLogin);
        tabela.addView(linha);

        linha = new TableRow (this);
        linha.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        linha.addView(textSenha);
        tabela.addView(linha);

        linha = new TableRow (this);
        linha.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        linha.addView(edtSenha);
        tabela.addView(linha);

        linha = new TableRow (this);
        linha.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        linha.addView(validar);
        tabela.addView(linha);

        //Iniciando tratativas para webservices
//      if(isOnline()==false)
//      {
//          AlertDialog.Builder alerta =  
//                  new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Atenção!").setMessage("Falha ao tentar conectar a internet ou servidor indisponível." );                       
//          alerta.setNeutralButton("Continuar", null);    
//          alerta.show();                      
//          return;                 
//      }               
    }


    /*************************************************    
     *METODO QUE VERIFICA SE HÁ CONEXÃO COM A INTERNET    
     *************************************************/
    public static boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            InetAddress.getByName("google.ca").isReachable(3);
            return true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e){           
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*********************************************************************************
     *              METODO PARA CARREGAR A INTERFACE DE CONTATO
     * *******************************************************************************/ 
    private SoapPrimitive autenticausuario(String prNome, String prsenha){

        System.out.println("AUTENTICANDO");
        SoapPrimitive sp = null;
        SOAP_ACTION = "autenticaReturn";
        METHOD_NAME = "autentica";      
        System.out.println("PREPARAR");
        try {           
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);    
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);             

            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            String a = ""+prNome+"/"+prsenha;
            pi.setName("dados");
            pi.setValue(a);
            pi.setType(String.class);       

            request.addProperty(pi);    
            HttpTransportSE Transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            Transport.debug = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);          
            Transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            System.out.println("Aqui");
            SoapObject body = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;                          
            SoapObject result= (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();//Instancia um vetor de objetos do tipo soapObject            

            String valida = result.toString();
            System.out.println("PARTE 5"+valida);
            if(valida.equals("ok")){
            System.out.println(valida);
            Retorno = 1;
            }else Retorno = 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sp;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //valida password. esta informação pode ser buscada no banco de dados.

        Login = edtLogin.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(Login);
        Senha = edtSenha.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(Senha);

        this.autenticausuario(Login, Senha);

        if(Retorno==1)
        {
            System.out.println("largura:"+width);
            System.out.println("largura:"+heigth);
            //mensagem de confirmação
            Toast.makeText(this, "Usuário autencitado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //chama a próxima activity/tela
            Intent prox_tela = new Intent(this, tela_opcao.class);
            startActivity(prox_tela);
        }else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login ou senha incorreto!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As boas práticas recomendam usar uma classe que herde de uma AsyncTask para tarefas de rede. Fazendo isso as requisições serão realizadas em uma Thread separada que depois atualiza a sua UI Thread (Tela/Activity).

Conforme a sua primeira linha de erro: **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**.

Pode-se notar que é um erro do sistema android devido ao uso de rede na Thread principal.

Esse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgRHopzzg9c) explica bem o funcionamento de uma AsyncTask.

Caso não resolva revise também a composição da sua requisição em SOAP observando se tudo está de acordo com o seu WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

como apontado pelo @FeedProject, você não pode chamar o WebService na `Thread` Principal.

Mas se por algum motivo você não quiser usar `AsyncTask`, como por exemplo ter um controle maior sobre as Threads, você pode usar `HandlerThread` e emular uma `AsyncTask`.

O codigo abaixo assume que o tipo X será o input de dados e o tipo Y o output.

```
public abstract class AsyncRunnable<X, Z> implements Runnable {

    private static HandlerThread handlerThread;
    private Handler handler;
    protected X[] parametros;
    protected CountDownLatch latch;
    protected Z retorno;

    public void run() {

    }

    protected AsyncRunnable() {
        if (AsyncRunnable.handlerThread == null) {
            AsyncRunnable.handlerThread =  new HandlerThread("WebServiceThread", android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            AsyncRunnable.handlerThread.start();
        }
        this.handler = new Handler(AsyncRunnable.handlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    public AsyncRunnable execute(X... parametros) {
        this.parametros = parametros;
        this.latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        this.handler.post(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Z get() {
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

        }
        return this.retorno;
    }
}
```

Caso precise chamar o mesmo:

```
AsyncRunnable<Object, Object> asyncRunnable = new AsyncRunnable<Object, Object>() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        this.retorno = webServiceClient.CallMethod(this.parametros[0], this.parametros[1]);
    }
};

Object[] input = new Object[] { new Object(), new Object() };
Object output = asyncRunnable.execute(input).get();
```

A unica diferença do codigo acima para o `AsyncTask` é que todas as chamadas ao WebService seram realizadas pela mesma `Thread`.

Lembrando que isto é apenas uma alternativa ao `AsyncTask`.